# Can't extract the element properly using the operator `$` in r when using the character variable

Tags: r

The codes are as follows

```
l1<-list(1,2)
names(l1)<-c("a","b")
l1$"b"
a<-"b"
l1$a
```

The output for `l1$"b"` is `2`,but for `l1$a` is `1`.
This is not consistent.I don't know why and how to deal with it.

I hope you can help me!
Thank you!

Comment: Try using `[[]]` like this `l1[[a]]`

Comment: Your code assigns the value "b" to a new variable `a`, not the named list element `a`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this functional notation

```
a<-"b"

`[[`(l1 , a)

#> 2
```

Answer (score 0):

To directly respond to your question about why this is the case: unlike the `[` and `[[` operators, the `$` operator [does not allow computed indices](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/R-lang.html#Indexing), i.e. The `name` used to index into `x` as in `x$name` must be a literal character string or symbol.

So, the semantics of l1$a is something like:

```
get(quote(a), envir = as.environment(l1), inherits = FALSE)
# Lightly modified from ?`$` for clarity
```

As langtang and Mohamed have noted above, you can use the `[` or `[[` operators instead which **do allow computed indices**.